Set Recursion Limit doesn't work in the standalone Python interpretator but works in online interpretators
Python 3.12.5
The algorithm for calculating the value of the function F(n), where n is a natural number, is given
by the following ratios:
F(n) = 1 for n = 1;
F(n) = 2 for n = 2;
F(n) = n * (n - 1) + F(n - 1) + F(n - 2) if n > 2.
What is the value of the expression F(2024) - F(2022) - 2 * F(2021) - F(2020)?

At first I just used recursion with the big limit, but I found out that the program runs TOOOOOOO slow (because I didn't use @lru_cache), I watched a video with the solution of this task and used this code
from functools import lru_cache
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(50000000)

@lru_cache
def F(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 2
    return n*(n-1) + F(n-1) + F(n-2)
print(F(2024) - F(2022) - 2*F(2021) - F(2020))

It worked for the author of the video. When I had tried it in an online interpretator, it worked too and I got the correct answer. But it doesn't work on my PC. I get RecursionError although I set the recursion limit to 50000000:
return n*(n-1) + F(n-1) + F(n-2)
                     ^^^^^^
[Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

What do I do? Maybe there are some other solutions?

There's no need to run the code to find the answer. Just use the definition of the function, it's a two minutes work to simplify the expression and get the simple numerical result. The choice of values was probably made so that people trying to bruteforce it would encounter recursion errors.

@ThierryLathuille
Well, I got the correct answer (12271520) thanks to this method. I just decided to solve all tasks without knowing the basis so I chose not the best method. But anyway it doesn't solve recursion errors

@ThierryLathuille anyway, thanks you

It seems you have bumped into the same bug as reported in issue #112215 - 3.12 setrecursionlimit is ignored in connection with @functools.cache. See also #112282. It looks like a major regression was introduced in 3.12 and is still present in 3.12.5.
For the actual challenge you try to solve, you don't need a function that calculates Fibonacci-like numbers at all. You can derive the answer by expanding the recursive -terms with greater arguments until we're left with an expression that just has a number of 2021 and 2020, which happen to cancel each other:
We start with:
      2024 − 2022 − 22021 − 2020
We can expand that 2024:
      2024⋅2023 + 2023 + 2022 − 2022 − 22021 − 2020
We can eliminate 2022 − 2022:
      2024⋅2023 + 2023 − 22021 − 2020
We can expand that 2023:
      2024⋅2023 + 2023⋅2022 + 2022 + 2021 − 22021 − 2020
We can reduce 2021 − 22021, to − 2021:
      2024⋅2023 + 2023⋅2022 + 2022 − 2021 − 2020
We can expand that 2022:
      2024⋅2023 + 2023⋅2022 + 2022⋅2021 + 2021 + 2020 − 2021 − 2020
We can now eliminate all  terms, and so the result is:
      2024⋅2023 + 2023⋅2022 + 2022⋅2021 = 12271520

0 is a wrong answer. Also calling setrecursionlimit() with 50000000 is not problematic. Python returns error only if I transmit the value more than 10**10

12271520 is the correct answer btw

I may be mistaken in terms, so let's just say that the 3000 limit does not solve the problem. I still get the same error

I might I have been to minimalistic with suggesting 3000. Set it to 6000, and it should work. You shouldn't get a stack trace with a mention of 996 recursive calls when you set the recursion depth to 6000. That works for me on different environments.

Sorry, I missed that F is not the F of standard Fibonacci, but has an extra term in the recurrence formula. I rewrote my answer to take that into account.

"works for me on different environments" - With what Python versions? (Not sure when exactly they made the relevant change, I think it was 3.12 or 3.11)

Good point, @nocomment. I just tried it again on 3.12.5 and the problem was reproduced. Turns out it is a reported bug.

Yep, that's it. You can btw "fix" it by avoiding the C implementation of functools, then the limit set by sys.setrecursionlimit does apply. But it's a hack.
